# C++: Can I make an assignment operator "explicit"

Tags: c++

I am on the task to migrate the concept of error handling in a C++ class library. Methods that previously simply returned bool (success/fail) shall be modified to return a `Result` object which conveys a machine readable error code and a human readable explanation (and some more which does not matter here).

Walking through thousands of lines of code is error prone, therefore I try to get the best support from the compiler for this task.

My result class has - among other member methods - a constructor that constructs the result from a code and an assignment operator for the code:

```
class Result
{
    public:
        typedef unsigned long ResultCode;
        explicit Result(ResultCode code); // (1)
        Result& operator=(ResultCode code); // (2)
};
```

Remark: I would usually use an enum class for `ResultCode` which would solve my problems, but this is not an option. This is because the major design objective was to use `Result` in different libraries, each of which shall define its own set of result codes without requiring one big header file that defines all possible result codes for all libraries. In fact, each class shall be able to define local result codes so that the list of possible result codes can be obtained from the classes header. Thus the codes cannot be enumerated in `Result`, they must be defined by the classes using the `Result` class.

To avoid implicit conversions on

```
return true;
```

Statements in the client code, the constructor has been declared explicit. But in nesting method calls, another problem occurs. Say, I have a method

```
bool doSomething()
{
    return true;
}
```

Which I am using in a function that returns a `Result` object. I want to forward result codes of nested calls

```
Result doSomethingElse
{
    Result result = doSomething();
    return result; 
}
```

With the current implementation of `Result`'s assignment operator, this is not going to give me a compiler error - the boolean return value of doSomething() is implicitly converted to unsigned long.

As I have read in the C++ documentation, only constructors and conversion operators may be declared explicit.

My questions

1. Why is explicit not allowed for assignment operators or other methods? IMO it would make a lot of sense to allow any method to be explicit as well.
2. Are there other solutions to prevent implicit type conversion for the assignment operator?

Comment: I know it's not the answer you want but why not use the exception mechanism in C++? Don't fight the language. Work with it. (Plus one for the nicely posed question though).

Comment: Couldn't you declare `template<typename T> void operator=(T) = delete;` and keep the one you have. It will use that one in normal case and will try to use deleted method for all other types.

Comment: I don't know if it's possible or even encouraged, but you could possibly extend [the system error classes](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error#System_error) instead of making it up all yourself?

Comment: I get `error: conversion from 'bool' to non-scalar type 'Result' requested` if I try this on coliru, not investigated further.

Comment: @Bathsheba: I would love to use exceptions and other C++ stuff. However the libraries shall be shipped as shared libraries, and throwing exceptions accross SL-boundaries is not recommended. Exceptions are used internally, but for the interfacing to the application they shall be converted to Result

Comment: @doug65536: Thank you, it appears to be the solution. I am getting other weird errors now, but it looks very promising.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: Which compiler are you using? Maybe I am missing MSVC 2013 options which would help me?

Comment: @kritzel_sw: for that kind of thing, I use a solution based on the lines of `IErrorInfo` of Microsoft's Component Object Model.

Comment: Your code above does not use assignment.  And nothing above precludes the use of `enum class`.  Your question reads like "I do not want to use a bbq to cook this cake.  The recipie says to use an oven at 350 F, and I cannot use a bbq because  I am allergic to bees.  Why does my oven not work?".  You understand how this makes it tricky to answer.  I mean, there are simularities between ovens and bbqs, and maybe the allergy to bees is not the real reason to avoid using the oven, and maybe your oven really does not work, but the question seems to belie confusion not describe a problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem isn't in the class `Result`: you *are* explicitly creating a new instance of it, after all; `explicit` cannot forbid it.

I don't think you can forbid the implicit promotion `bool -> long`.

You can work around it. One way is to make `ResultCode` *not* be an integer type. then, *it* could have an explicit constructor. Something like

```
class ResultCode 
{
unsigned long m_code;
public:
explicit ResultCode(unsigned long code) : m_code(code) {}
operator unsigned long () { return m_code; } 
};
```

would allow you to use `ResultCode` anywhere you can use a `unsigned int` and create it as `ResultCode res = 5` or `return ResultCode(5)` but not call a function expecting a `ResultCode` (such as the `Result` constructor!) with anything which is not a `ResultCode` already, nor do something like `return 5` if the function must return a `ReturnCode`.

Otherwise you can use template overloadng to 'catch' anything not being an `unsigned int` and force it to be an error

```
typedef unsigned long ResultCode;

class Result
{
    ResultCode m_par;

public: 
    template<typename T>
    Result(T param) { static_assert(false); }

    template<>
    Result(ResultCode par): m_par(par) {}
};

int main()
{
    ResultCode a = 5;     //ok
    //unsigned long a = 6;  //also ok
    //bool a = true;      //error!
    //int a = 7;          //also error!!
    Result b(a);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> With the current implementation of Result's assignment operator, this is not going to give me a compiler error - the boolean return value of doSomething() is implicitly converted to unsigned long.

With respect to the code you posted; it does result in an error `error: no viable conversion from 'bool' to 'Result'`, [see here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2785bb21853021c5).

A minimal example showing the behaviour you see in the code would be required. There is likely other constructors or type with conversion in the actual code that have a material effect on your code.

---

On the explicitly asked questions...

> Why is explicit not allowed for assignment operators or other methods?

`explicit` is only allowed where implicit conversion can take place, i.e. where the compiler would attempt to generate the conversion for you (there is a special case for `bool`). Such conversions are constructors and the conversion (or casting operators).

Marking the constructor or conversion operator as `explicit` prevents the compiler from making the conversions, hence, if you require the conversion, you need to be explicit about it - as a general motivation for why this is done, it makes the code more explicit in what it does. There is a trade-off, so judicious use should be applied in both cases. The general advice is to favour `explicit` when in doubt.

For example;

```
struct Result {
  Result(long src); // can be marked explicit
  operator long() const; // can be marked explicit
};
```

> Are there other solutions to prevent implicit type conversion for the assignment operator?

The assignment operator has a particular for `Result& operator=(Result&);`. In the assignment itself, there are no conversion. To prevent the implicit creation of a `Result` for the assignment, the constructor(s) need to be marked `explicit`.

To prevent the `Result` from being created from a `ResultCode`, you can either not declare the method, or mark it as deleted;

```
Result& operator=(ResultCode code) = delete;
```

Comment: If it is not conversion, what is then happening behind the scenes of a Result result = true; then which leaves me with a Result code of 1

Comment: What compiler are you using? That gives me an error in gcc, clang and msvc.

Comment: @kritzel_sw. Do you have a minimal example showing the compilation (which is not as you expected)?

Comment: will try to strip it down. Will need a few days as I am about to leave for a business trip